# Multiply all columns in dataframe by single column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to multiply all columns of a *dataframe* by single column.

```
df1 <- data.frame(F1=c(1,5,8,9),F2=c(1,5,8,9),F3=c(1,5,8,9))
> df1
  F1 F2 F3
1  1  1  1
2  5  5  5
3  8  8  8
4  9  9  9

C <- data.frame(C=c(2,1,2,0.5))
> C
    C
1 2.0
2 1.0
3 2.0
4 0.5
```

I wanna multiply each column of `df1` by C.
I have tried:

```
df2<-df1[,c(1:3)]*C[,1]
df2<-df1*C
df2< df1%*%C
```

and

```
for(i in 2:length(names(b))) {
+     df2 <- C[, 1] * b[, i]
+ }
```

Comment: do `df = sapply(df1, '*', C$C)`

Comment: `apply(df1,2,function(x){x*C})`

Comment: Thanks it worked! I knew it was something simple but I'm new in R.

Comment: I'm assuming that where you have `a` you mean `C`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also try

```
df1 * t(C)
#    F1   F2   F3
#1  2.0  2.0  2.0
#2  5.0  5.0  5.0
#3 16.0 16.0 16.0
#4  4.5  4.5  4.5
```

---

When we try to multiply data frames they must be of the same size.

```
df1 * C
```

> error in Ops.data.frame(df1, C) : 
>     ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

`t()` turns `C` into a matrix, i.e. a vector with dimension attribute of length 4. This vector gets recycled when we multiply it with `df1`.

What would also work in the same way (and might be faster than transposing `C`):

```
df1 * C$C
```

or

```
df1 * unlist(C)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can vectorize the multiplication by `rep`licating the 'C' column

```
df1 * C[row(df1)]
#     F1   F2   F3
#1  2.0  2.0  2.0
#2  5.0  5.0  5.0
#3 16.0 16.0 16.0
#4  4.5  4.5  4.5
```

Or use the `rep` explicitly

```
df1 * rep(C$C, ncol(df1))
```

Answer (score 4):

The overkill dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate_all(.,function(col){C$C*col})
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of good code only answers here, so I thought I'd explain what was going wrong.

The problem is that you are trying to do the multiply (`*`) function on a list of columns, which is what a data frame is.  For multiplying by a single column (C) from a second data frame (C) you would refer to that single column as either `C$C` `C["C"]`, `C[,1]` or `C[1]`.  If you did `df1[,1]*C[,1]`  or one of the other ways of referring to the first column of df1 it would work fine.  But the challenge is you want to do all of the columns.

Therefore you need to use a strategy for applying the multiplication function to a list of columns.  There are even more ways to do this than have already been given. For example:

```
 as.data.frame(lapply(df1, `*`, C$C))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is `` sweep(df1, 1, C$C, `*`) ``, which means "sweep out" the statistic represented by `C$C` from each column of `df1` by multiplication.