# Create new columns by multiplying some columns in dataframe by single column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to generate multiple new columns by multiplying some columns in a dataframe by a single column in R and append the new columns to the original df.

I have the initial data formatted as follows

```
ID  amount  supplier_1  supplier_2   supplier_3 ... supplier_100
1   10       0               1            0             0
1   15       1               0            0             0
1   20       1               0            0             0
2    5       0               0            0             1
2    8       0               1            0             0
2   10       0               0            0             1

#I have more than 100 suppliers in this df.
```

What I want to have as output is to multiply all supplier_n columns  (dummy vars) by amount.

```
ID  amount  supplier_1  supplier_2   supplier_3 ... supplier_100  
1   10       0               1            0             0                 
1   15       1               0            0             0                 
1   20       1               0            0             0                 
2    5       0               0            0             1                 
2    8       0               1            0             0                 
2   10       0               0            0             1                 


amt*supplier_1   amt*supplier_2  amt*supplier_3 ..... amt*supplier_100   Total_amt 
 0               10               0                      0                 45 
15                0               0                      0                 45
20                0               0                      0                 45
 0                0               0                      5                 23
 0                8               0                      0                 23
 0                0               0                     10                 23


#total_amt is the sum of amount conditional on ID.
```

I find a similar here and tried the mutate_all with function(col) commands but did not work

[Multiply all columns in dataframe by single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705656/multiply-all-columns-in-dataframe-by-single-colum).

Would greatly appreciate it if any one can provide some suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` with `mutate()` and `across()` to perform the same action on many columns. For example

```
dd %>% mutate(across(starts_with("supplier"), ~amount * .x))
#   ID amount supplier_1 supplier_2 supplier_3 supplier_100
# 1  1     10          0         10          0            0
# 2  1     15         15          0          0            0
# 3  1     20         20          0          0            0
# 4  2      5          0          0          0            5
# 5  2      8          0          8          0            0
# 6  2     10          0          0          0           10
```

To add the total amount, if you assume that only one supplier has a value and it's either 0/1, you just sum the amounts by ID with

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("supplier"), ~amount * .x)) %>% 
  mutate(Total_amt = sum(amount), .by=ID)
```

Tested with sample data

```
dd <- read.table(text="
ID  amount  supplier_1  supplier_2   supplier_3  supplier_100
1   10       0               1            0             0
1   15       1               0            0             0
1   20       1               0            0             0
2    5       0               0            0             1
2    8       0               1            0             0
2   10       0               0            0             1", header=T)
```

Comment: thank you! would it be possible to keep original supplier_x data and append amount*supplier_x to the original df using mutate(across())?

Comment: @sam you can add `.names = "amount_x_{col}"` inside the `mutate` - so would look like: `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("supplier"), ~amount * .x, .names = "amount_x_{col}"))`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `lapply` to simultaneously create new columns while performing the operations:

```
ccols <- names(df)[grep("supplier", names(df))]
# [1] "supplier_1"   "supplier_2"   "supplier_3"   "supplier_100"

df[paste0("amt_x_",ccols)] <- lapply(df[ccols], \(x) df$amount * x)
```

Output:

```
#   ID amount supplier_1 supplier_2 supplier_3 supplier_100 amt_x_supplier_1 amt_x_supplier_2 amt_x_supplier_3 amt_x_supplier_100
# 1  1     10          0          1          0            0                0               10                0                  0
# 2  1     15          1          0          0            0               15                0                0                  0
# 3  1     20          1          0          0            0               20                0                0                  0
# 4  2      5          0          0          0            1                0                0                0                  5
# 5  2      8          0          1          0            0                0                8                0                  0
# 6  2     10          0          0          0            1                0                0                0                 10
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID  amount  supplier_1  supplier_2   supplier_3  supplier_100
1   10       0               1            0             0
1   15       1               0            0             0
1   20       1               0            0             0
2    5       0               0            0             1
2    8       0               1            0             0
2   10       0               0            0             1", h = TRUE)
```

Or if you just want to replace the existing values in the desired columns, just do the following to overwrite the columns:

```
df[ccols] <- lapply(df[ccols], \(x) df$amount * x)
```

Output:

```
#   ID amount supplier_1 supplier_2 supplier_3 supplier_100
# 1  1     10          0         10          0            0
# 2  1     15         15          0          0            0
# 3  1     20         20          0          0            0
# 4  2      5          0          0          0            5
# 5  2      8          0          8          0            0
# 6  2     10          0          0          0           10
```

Answer (score 0):

You (and other answerers) may want to recall R is vectorized and uses recycling, means you can also mutliplicate an entire matrix with a vector. Really no need to `lapply` or the like here.

```
scls <- grep('^supplier_\\d+$', names(df))
df[scls] <- df[scls]*df$amount

df
#   ID amount supplier_1 supplier_2 supplier_3 supplier_100
# 1  1     10          0         10          0            0
# 2  1     15         15          0          0            0
# 3  1     20         20          0          0            0
# 4  2      5          0          0          0            5
# 5  2      8          0          8          0            0
# 6  2     10          0          0          0           10
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), amount = c(10L, 
15L, 20L, 5L, 8L, 10L), supplier_1 = c(0L, 15L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), supplier_2 = c(10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L), supplier_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), supplier_100 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 10L
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```